# Filter Dates Between Two Specific Dates In an Excel Column using C# Interop

Tags: c#, date, excel-interop, autofilter

Just trying to filter a column in Excel using c#.
My Focus is to filter a column based on Two Dates.

Input_1 : From date (dd-mmm-yy) eg: 01-Dec-18

Input_2 : To date (dd-mmm-yy) eg: 10-Dec-18

The Excel Column contains random dates in dd-mm-yyyy (eg: 07-11-2018)

How is it possible to apply a filter in this column so that I can get the Column Dates modified within the Dates mentioned as Input_1 and Input_2

[image]

What I tried to apply a filter to column :

`excelRange.AutoFilter(excelDATESColumn_Number,FromDateInput_1,Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd,Missing.Value, true);`

Still no help!
I am starting to think, it is not possible via Interop to do this!!

Comment: @ainwood:  `range1.AutoFilter(cHireDate, "<01/01/2014");` Thanks.This one came so close but how to apply BETWEEN 2 Dates.. Still I wonder!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following piece of code works for me. You just need to pass the additional parameters to AutoFilter method.

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2018, 11, 06);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2018, 11, 13);
var r = excelRange.AutoFilter(3, ">=" + dt1.ToOADate(), Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, "<=" + dt2.ToOADate());
```

Notice, I had to convert the date to OADate for this to work correctly.

Comment: do you have any idea on this one,: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53831269/position-an-arrow-inside-excel-chart-using-interop-c-sharp