# Indication in Stacked chart for MIN, MAX (stuck here for a month ..)

Tags: c#, charts, excel-interop, excel-charts

Stuck in trying to adjust an arrow (sort of) inside an Excel chart.

I have a column chart with series of data.
I want to point out minimum, maximum, and average value from the chart.
What i was planning is, to mark it by an arrow.

**Is it possible** via C#?

For the below chart, I want to indicate MIN & MAX, like the ones I have drawn.

[image]

I started by getting the charts by this:

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook book;
Excel.Worksheet sheet;
Excel.ChartObject chartObj;
Excel.Chart chart;

book = app.Workbooks.Open(@"Path to workbook");//Open the work book
sheet = book.Sheets["sheet name"];//Select the sheet the chart is on
chartObj = sheet.ChartObjects("Chart name");//Select the ChartObject
chart = chartObj.Chart; //Select the Chart from the ChartObjec
```

## Findings:

**I could not even find a general way - to represent min,max in a stacked chart.**

Comment: It will be easier to change the colour of min and max instead of positioning your arrow. I know it is possible in excel to change colours but haven't tried it using c# and interop. Check this: https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/label-excel-chart-min-and-max for an example of how it is implemented in Excel.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal : Kindly see my Update: I cant change the color of the chart. I need an indication in the chart as I do have stacked graphs as well !!!